# $\epsilon$-proof for the limit $f(x)=\frac{1}{\cosh{(x)}}+\log{\left ( \frac{\cosh{(x)}}{1+\cosh{(x)}} \right )}$ as $x$ goes to $\pm \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, epsilon-delta

I want to use a $\epsilon,\delta$-proof for the existence and value for the limit of $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\cosh{(x)}}+\log{\left ( \frac{\cosh{(x)}}{1+\cosh{(x)}} \right )}$$
for $x \rightarrow \pm\infty$.

Now, I know the definition for such proof to be:

#### 1. Limit as $x \to +\infty$

$$\lim_{x \ \to \  +\infty} f(x) = L \Leftrightarrow 
  \forall \ \epsilon>0\; (\exists \ \delta : (\;x>\delta\implies |f(x) - L|\leq\epsilon))
$$

#### 2. Limit as $x \to -\infty$

$$\lim_{x \ \to \  -\infty} f(x) = L \Leftrightarrow 
  \forall \ \epsilon>0\; (\exists \ \delta : (\;x<\delta\implies |f(x) - L|\leq\epsilon))
$$

#### 3. Limit evaluating to +$\infty$

$$\lim_{x \ \to \  a} f(x) = +\infty \Leftrightarrow \forall M  > 0 \ (\exists \  \delta > 0  \ : \ (0<|x-a|<\delta \implies f(x) >M)$$

#### 4. Limit evaluating to -$\infty$

$$\lim_{x \ \to \  a} f(x) = -\infty \Leftrightarrow \forall  N  < 0 \ (\exists \  \delta > 0  \ : \ (0<|x-a|<\delta \implies f(x)  < N)$$

I am struggeling to approach this problem as;

1. Wouldn't I need to know what the limit is before doing the actual proof and thus not being able to know which method to use?

This one seems rather complex and I am completly lost. Can someone explain to me how to identify and "attack" such a problem?

Comment: Do you know the definition of $\cosh(x)$?

Comment: What's complex about it? That limit is $0$. And what has this to do with [tag:functional-analysis]?

Comment: @MarkViola yes I do

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Fixed now. I am unsure on how to begin the proof, formally.

Comment: And informally how do you deal with it?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I would just from prievious courses i.e replace the cosh with the definitions, take the limits of the individual sums and just do regular arithmetic. I have had analysis for a week*

Comment: @mathstudent23 And after you apply the definition and take the limit, what do you find?

Comment: @MarkViola I am STRUGGELING to apply the definitions. I do not know why but I just do not get it. Coming from getting a 99+% in linear algebra and now completly struggeling I do not know what but I. do. not. get. it. It is extremly sad.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos But that way I find a limit and I find it to be 0 for both because of symmetri from the symmetri of hypbolic cosine. This does not proof it by the definitions above, though.

Comment: You have asked “Wouldn't I need to know what the limit is before doing the actual proof and thus not being able to know which method to use?” This suggested that you didn't even know what was the limit. Now that you know it, you also know what is the relevant definition.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes but I would then be postulating that the limit is 0 from both sides  of $x$. But yes - that would be definition 1 if my assessment is correct. From my understanding I was not able to find a limit 'by guessing' and then use some definition on the function.

Comment: @mathstudent23 Hi! I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS:**

Note that the hyperbolic cosine function is even and so we need only examine the case $x\to +\infty$.

Then, apply the inequalities

$$\frac{y}{1+y}\le \log(y)\le y-1$$

and

$$0<\frac1{\cosh(x)}\le 2e^{-x}$$

Comment: I get the first part about the function being even (I showed this prievously) and thus only consider the 1 case. But applying the definition and thus the inequality is unclear for me.

Comment: @mathstudent23 Hi! I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With $y:=\operatorname{sech}x>0$ this becomes $f=y-\ln(1+y)\sim\tfrac12y^2$, so the limit is $0$. We wish to prove $\forall\varepsilon>0\exists\delta>0\forall y(y<\delta\implies|f|<\varepsilon)$. Since $0<f<\tfrac12y^2$, we can choose $\delta=\sqrt{2\varepsilon}$. In particular, $\tfrac12y^2-y+\ln(1+y)=\int_0^y\tfrac{z^2}{1+z}dz>0$. The bound $y<\sqrt{2\varepsilon}$ is, of course, equivalent to $|x|>\operatorname{arcosh}\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\varepsilon}}$.

Comment: I have never seen such a method before. To specify, the integral part loses me a bit as I have only had the course for a week and not allowed to use calc results etc.

Comment: @mathstudent23 Don't worry, I'm sure you can convince yourself $y-\ln(1+y)$ has a $O(y^2)$ upper bound some other way.

Comment: Okay I see. But we can basically "not use" the integral and just use the rest of the prove as is, as it still holds for the inequalities?

Comment: and wouldn't the problem become $f=y+\ln(1+y)$

Comment: @mathstudent23 No:$$\ln(1+y)=\ln(1+\operatorname{sech}x)=\ln\tfrac{1+\cosh x}{\cosh x}=-\ln\tfrac{\cosh x}{1+\cosh x}.$$

Comment: Okay thanks so all that is left is to find the upper bound to be as described